# Finding MST such that a specific vertex has a minimum degree

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, degrees, kruskals-algorithm

Given undirected, connected graph G={V,E}, a vertex in V(G), label him v, and a weight function f:E->R+(Positive real numbers), I need to find a MST such that v's degree is minimal. I've already noticed that if all the edges has unique weight, the MST is unique, so I believe it has something to do with repetitive weights on edges. I though about running Kruskal's algorithm, but when sorting the edges, I'll always consider edges that occur on v last. For example, if (a,b),(c,d),(v,e) are the only edges of weight k, so the possible permutations of these edges in the sorted edges array are: {(a,b),(c,d),(v,e)} or {(c,d),(a,b),(v,e)}. I've ran this variation over several graphs and it seems to work, but I couldn't prove it. Does anyone know how to prove the algorithm's correct (Meaning proving v's degree is minimal), or give a contrary example of the algorithm failing?

Comment: 1. I would start by proving that every possible MST can be generated by the Kruskal algorithm (algorithm's execution is completely determined by the order of edges with the same weight). 2. Then I would compare any execution of the Kruskal algorithm with the execution you suggested, and I would try to conclude that your execution produces less edges incident to `v`.

Answer (score 1):

First note that Kruskal's algorithm can be applied to any weighted graph, whether or not it is connected. In general it results in a minimum-weight spanning *forest* (MSF), with one MST for each connected component. To prove that your modification of Kruskal's algorithm succeeds in finding the MST for which `v` has minimal degree, it helps to prove the slightly stronger result that if you apply your algorithm to a possibly disconnected graph then it succeeds in finding the MSF where the degree of `v` is minimized.

The proof is by induction on the number, `k`, of distinct weights.

Basis Case (`k = 1`). In this case weights can be ignored and we are trying to find a spanning forest in which the degree of `v` is minimized. In this case, your algorithm can be described as follows: pick edges for as long as possible according to the following two rules:

> 1) No selected edge forms a cycle with previously selected edges
>
> 2) An edge involving `v` isn't selected unless any edge which doesn't
>   involve `v` violates rule 1.

Let `G'` denote the graph from which `v` and all incident edges have been removed from `G`. It is easy to see that the algorithm in this special case works as follows. It starts by creating a spanning forest for `G'`. Then it takes those trees in the forest that are contained in `v's` connected component in the original graph `G` and connects each component to `v` by a single edge. Since the components connected to `v` in the second stage can be connected to each other in no other way (since if any connecting edge not involving `v` exists it would have been selected by rule 2) it is easy to see that the degree of `v` is minimal.

Inductive Case: Suppose that the result is true for `k` and `G` is a weighted graph with `k+1` distinct weights and `v` is a specified vertex in `G`. Sort the distinct weights in increasing order (so that weight `k+1` is the longest of the distinct weights -- say `w_{k+1}`). Let `G'` be the sub-graph of `G` with the same vertex set but with all edges of weight `w_{k+1}` removed. Since the edges are sorted in the order of increasing weight, note that the modified Kruskal's algorithm in effect *starts* by applying itself to `G'`. Thus -- by the induction hypothesis prior to considering edges of weight `w_{k+1}`, the algorithm has succeeded in constructing an MSF `F'` of `G'` for which the degree, `d'` of `v` in `G'` is minimized.

As a final step, modified Kruskal's applied to the overall graph `G` will merge certain of the trees in `F'` together by adding edges of weight `w_{k+1}`. One way to conceptualize the final step is the think of `F'` as a graph where two trees are connected exactly when there is an edge of weight `w_{k+1}` from some node in the first tree to some node in the second tree. We have (almost) the basis case with `F'`. Modified Kruskal's will add edged of weight `w_{k+1}` until it can't do so anymore -- and won't add an edge connecting to `v` unless there is no other way to connect to trees in `F'` that need to be connected to get a spanning forest for the original graph `G`.

The final degree of `v` in the resulting MSF is `d = d'+d"` where `d"` is the number of edges of weight `w_{k+1}` added at the final step. Neither `d'` nor `d"` can be made any smaller, hence it follows that `d` can't be made any smaller (since the degree of `v` in any spanning forest can be written as the sum of the number of edges whose weight is less than `w_{k+1}` coming into `v` and the number off edges of weight `w_{k+1}` coming into `v`).

QED.

There is still an element of hand-waving in this, especially with the final step -- but Stack Overflow isn't a peer-reviewed journal. Anyway, the overall logic should be clear enough.

One final remark -- it seems fairly clear that Prim's algorithm can be similarly modified for this problem. Have you looked into that?